# AngularJS Routed Page Not Showing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, routes

So quick question I've been looking at this code for awhile but cannot find why, it just gives me the output on the page

```
Partials/View1.html
```

I'm not trying to just post here whenever I run into some small issue but this has been baffling me for awhile now, and I get no errors on the console. I run the code from http://plnkr.co/edit/sN9TagVBOdX3mkrxaTiu?p=preview, mentioned on another post and it works fine, but I don't get the right output from this. The following is the index.html (the main page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
</head> 
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>


        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

My script look likes:

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);

            demoApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/',
                      {
                        controller: 'SimpleController',
                        template: 'Partials/View1.html'
                      })
                .when('/partial2',
                     {
                        controller: 'SimpleController',
                        template: 'Partials/View2.html'
                    })
                .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});
         } );

    demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.customers = [
            {name: 'John Smith', city: 'Phoenix'},
            {name: 'Jane Doe', city: 'New York'},
            {name: 'John Doe', city: 'San Francisco'}
        ];

        $scope.addCustomer = function() {
            $scope.customers.push({ 
                name: $scope.newCustomer.name,
                city: $scope.newCustomer.city

            });
        }
    });
```

And I don't get what is supposed to be shown from the view1.html, I just get what I showed up above. This is the code

```
<div class="container">
<h2>View 1</h2>
Name: 
<br>
<input type="text" ng-model="filter.name">
<br>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:filter.name | orderBy: 'city'">{{ cust.name }} - {{ cust.city }}</li>
</ul>

<br>
Customer name: <br>
<input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.name">
Customer city: <br>
<input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.city">
<br>
<button ng-click="addCustomer()">Add Customer</button>
<br>
<a href="#/view2">View 2</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you should be using templateUrl instead of template:

```
.when('/partial2',
   {
     controller: 'SimpleController',
     templateUrl: 'Partials/View2.html'
   })
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: Wow, I was afraid of this. Looked over everything, no errors and somehow in the back of my mind I figured it would be something stupid like that. Thanks.

Comment: don't sweat it, @theman55, these kinds of errors are nearly impossible to find by yourself when you've spent a long time looking at your own code. it's much easier for someone who didn't write it to jump in and find the bug